# How can I set the response header of a SonarQube webservice response?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a custom SonarQube webservice, and would like SonarQube to compress the response.

As the `org.sonar.api.server.ws.Response` class has a `stream()` method which returns an object implementing `org.sonar.api.server.ws.Response.Stream` interface I decided to use it. This interface has an `output()` method that returns an `OutputStream` instance (great). I was then hoping to be able to do something like:

```
OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.stream().output();
OutputStream compressedOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(responseOutputStream);
// Here I write what I need to my compressed stream
```

But then I should also be able to set the value of the `Content-Encoding` header to `gzip`... but I have no clue how to do it as the `Response` interface does not provide a way to set response headers.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

P.S. I'm aiming at SonarQube version >= 4.5.x

Answer (score 0):

HTTP responses are automatically compressed if request header "Accept-Encoding" contains value "gzip", so no need for managing that by yourself.

The response to the question is no, API does not allow to set response headers. It will be added later if needed.

Comment: Consider it being needed then :-)

Comment: If it's for compression, then it's not a valid reason !